# Email sending issues 1.9.x

Tags: email, magento1.9.3

I am having a terrible time sending emails to our distributors on orders placed. Order confirmations go to customer. Shipping confirmations go to customer. No new order confirmations go to warehouse for distribution. Can anyone help with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since **Magento 1.9.1**, the emails are not being sent **directly** during checkout but instead are being queued. The queue is being processed via your Magento cronjob.

There were some changes to email in **Magento 1.9.1** from the Magento 1.9.1 release notes. Two things jump out as requiring further investigation:

> “all Magento e-mails (including order confirmation and transactional)
>   are now queued and sent according to your configured cron schedule”
>
> “boasts responsive default email templates so customers can read your order confirmation emails and newsletters on any device”

I suggest you to install this free extension [SMTP Pro](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html), set the SMTP config  connexion like Gmail for exemple, and **dont forget** to set `Queue Usage` to `never`, save and your problem is solved.

Comment: Using email queueing during checkout has the benefit of the email sending process not slowing down your checkout.

Comment: You talk about Benefits ?, euhh give me just one ? and to answer you I never said that it slows down the checkout !